# Strings In Array Need Formatting

Tags: php, arrays, string, format, data-manipulation

I have an array of strings such as:

```
$testArray =  array ('here I am going to have a string that is over 50 charactersss ', 'where I am going to hav string that is over 50 charactersss');
```

I need to basically create a function which will take the array or arrays and count the length of the strings. If it is more than 30 characters then it will perform this action which is remove the items from the array and create a string with new lines which are not more than 30 characters long and words are intact like this:

```
'here I am going to have a
string that is over 50 where
I am going to have a string 
that is over 50 charactersss'
```

So far I have played around for days but can't get this to work...

This is what I have tried I need a way of counting if a string length in array is more than 30 then i can apply something like this:

```
public function textFunction($content = [])
{
    $rawText       = implode(' ', $content);
    $cleanText     = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', 
    str_replace("\n", " ", $rawText)));
    $formattedText = wordwrap($cleanText, 30, "\n");
    return $formattedText;
}
```

The above works but how do I check if content is more than 30 characters inside an array to perform this i would have to loop content but then won't be able to do the above if that makes sense.

Comment: That's a good description of the problem, but what's really important here is to show what you've tried. Even a wildly misguided attempt is better than nothing: It shows you're committed to solving the problem.

Comment: Use [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

Comment: This is what I have tried I need a way of counting if a string length in array is more than 30 then i can apply something like this:

Comment: What do you want to do with strings shorter than 30 characters? Remove them entirely? `wordwrap` only has an effect if the string is longer than the `$width` parameter.

Comment: yes the string can be completely formatted if above 30 this is the key part

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [`wordwrap`:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$testArray =  array ('here I am going to have a string that is over 50 charactersss ', 'where I am going to hav string that is over 50 charactersss');

$newarray = [];
foreach ($testArray as $str) {
    $newarray = array_merge($newarray,explode("\n",wordwrap($str,30)));
}
```

Resulting array (dumped):

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "here I am going to have a"
  [1]=>
  string(22) "string that is over 50"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "charactersss "
  [3]=>
  string(30) "where I am going to hav string"
  [4]=>
  string(28) "that is over 50 charactersss"
}
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8987b80df4cbe9876568e64a9e983a8c3a492606